# Надо ли делать private функции nodiscard?

Tags: c++, классы

Правильно ли вешать `nodiscard` на `private` функции? Например `is_empty()` публичная функция становится `private`. Надо ли убирать `nodiscard`? Ведь по идее `private` функции недоступны пользователю, а значит игнорирование их значений может возникнуть только в реализации класса, т.е. это внутренняя логическая ошибка, которая интересна только разработчику библиотеки, а не пользователю этого класса.

Comment: Функцию следует делать `[[nodiscard]]`, если у неё нет побочных действий: функция не меняет состояние класса, не обращается к статическим объектам, не пишет в устройства ввода-вывода. Возможно, она уже помечена как `const`. Функция `is_empty`, вероятно, подходит для `[[nodiscard]]`. В остальных случаях, на мой взгляд, нужно исходить из сути самой функции и возвращаемого значения. Уровень доступа значения не имеет.

Comment: *"внутренняя логическая ошибка, которая интересна только разработчику библиотеки"* Значит это ваше как разработчика библиотеки личное дело. Хотя безопаснее не уберать, очевидно.

Comment: `[[nodiscard]]` следует использовать во всех ситуациях, когда возвращаемое значение должно использоваться. @maestro Похоже, что вы перепутали этот аттрибут с каким-то другим.

Comment: @user7860670, я не перепутал. Я так написал, потому что если функция не имеет побочных действий, то возвращаемое значение - единственный способ узнать, что эта функция сделала. В таких случаях возвращаемое значение *должно* использоваться, а иначе зачем эту функцию вообще вызывать.

Comment: @maestro Не всегда отсутствие сайд-эффектов равно необходимости обрабатывать результат. Иногда и эффекты есть, и результат важный.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, у вас какое-то нелогичное заявление. Сначала вы говорите: "Не всегда отсутствие сайд-эффектов равно необходимости обрабатывать результат".  Ожидается, что далее вы будете пояснять эту мысль. Но следующее предложение никак не связано с первым: "Иногда и эффекты есть, и результат важный". С этим утверждением я и не спорил. Даже пример могу привести: `operator new` имеет побочные эффекты в виде модификации таблицы свободных блоков, его возвращаемое значение нельзя отбрасывать, и он действительно помечен атрибутом `[[nodiscard]]`.

Comment: Но бесполезность вызова функции без побочных эффектов, не обрабатывая возвращаемое значение, вы не опровергли.

Comment: @maestro *"С этим утверждением я и не спорил."* Прочитал ваш первый комментарий еще раз, согласился. *"следующее предложение никак не связано с первым"* Почему же. Сначала я пишу, что отсутствие сайд-эффектов не всегда эквивалентно необходимости обрабатывать результат. Потом уточняю, почему не эквивалентно - потому что бывают функции, которые и сайд-эффекты имеют, и результат нужно обрабатывать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, если вы имеете в виду отношение логической эквиваленции, то тогда в этом есть смысл. Эквиваленция, в отличие от импликации, работает в обе стороны. Существует даже определение эквиваленции через две зеркальные импликации.